# apex:commandButton renders incorrectly

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton

According to the  Salesforce API, an `<apex:commandButton>` should render as `<input type="submit">` however in my visualforce page, it renders as `<input type="button">`. Anyone know why this might be happening, and how to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
<apex:commandButton value="View Applicable Offerings" action="{!getOfferings}" status="status" styleClass="centered btn btn-default" rerender="results, messages" id="getOfferingsButton"/>
<apex:actionFunction name="search" action="{!getOfferings}" status="status" rerender="resultsBlock"/>
<apex:actionStatus id="status" styleClass="centered">  
    <apex:facet name="start">
        <img src="/img/loading.gif" class="centered" />
    </apex:facet>
</apex:actionStatus>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the apex:commandButton uses a reRender attribute, it renders as a button, otherwise it renders as a submit.

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit 1" rerender="form"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit 2"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Observe the generated HTML for this page and you'll see the difference.

This is semantically correct, because the former doesn't actually submit the form directly (it uses AJAX). The documentation is most likely just incomplete, because it only provides one example.

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks!